# Conditional reactivity Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Reactive expressions in Shiny propagate changes where they need to go. We can suppress some of this behaviour with `isolate`, but can we suppress changes being propagated based on our own logical expression?

The example I give is a simple scatterplot, and we draw a crosshair with `abline` where the user clicks. Unfortunately, Shiny considers the result to be a new plot, and our click value is reset to `NULL`... which in turn is treated as an update to the value to be propagated as usual. The plot is redrawn, and `NULL` is passed to both arguments of `abline`.

My hack (commented out below) is to place a condition in the `renderPlot` call which updates some non-reactive variables for the plotting coordinates, only when the click values are non-`NULL`. This works fine for trivial plots, but it actually results in the plot being drawn twice.

What's a better way to do this? Is there a *correct* way?

Server file:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function (input, output)
{
  xclick <- yclick <- NULL
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    #if (!is.null(input$click$x)){
      xclick <<- input$click$x
      yclick <<- input$click$y
    #}
    plot(1, 1)
    abline(v = xclick, h = yclick)
  })
})
```

UI file:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
  basicPage(
    plotOutput("plot", click = "click", height = "400px", width = "400px")
  )
)
```

Comment: Since your `if` statement seems to do what you want with this example it might be good to provide an example of when it doesn't work

Comment: `renderPlot` is somewhat static, to do what you want you should use more advanced libraries like `rCharts` or `highcharter` only to invoke those changes

Comment: Like [this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/actionButton.html)?

Comment: @Hack-R I consider the fact that my fix results in plotting the same thing twice to be pretty bad!

Comment: @Pork Chop Thanks for the suggestions. I am implementing my default interactive graphics in other ways... I'm just trying to provide a Shiny alternative.

Comment: @alistaire I don't think this gets around the problem, but please provide an example if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Winston calls this problem "state" accumulation - you want to display not only the current data, but something generated by the previous plot (the best place to learn about this is at https://www.rstudio.com/resources/videos/coordinated-multiple-views-linked-brushing/)

The basic idea is to create your own set of reactive values, and update them when the user clicks on the plot. They won't be invalidated until the next click, so you don't get circular behaviour.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  shinyUI(basicPage(plotOutput("plot", click = "click"))),
  function(input, output) {
    click <- reactiveValues(x = NULL, y = NULL)
    observeEvent(input$click, {
      click$x <- input$click$x
      click$y <- input$click$y
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      plot(1, 1)
      abline(v = click$x, h = click$y)
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I take it from this that we can't currently control invalidations with our own logical expression? I assume this solution relies on observeEvent having `ignoreNULL = TRUE`, and that in the general case, we couldn't suppress updating if `input$click$x` was 2 or something. If this is the case, I might just edit the question to refer more to stopping circular behaviour.

Comment: You can, but it'd be trickier. I think it might be better to ask a new question

Comment: The link provided by @hadley on your answer no longer works. If there is a better place to learn this please post it. I want to learn about state accumulation.

Comment: @LazarusThurston I don't remember exactly what was at that link, but it might have been this https://www.rstudio.com/resources/shiny-dev-con/brushing-ggvis/